# MySQL returning PDO placeholder names

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-update

There's a `[similar post][1]`, but without a solution.

The following code is resulting in a MySQL query containing the placeholder names:

```
    $the_image_itself = "abcde123def.jpg";
    $title = "A Book";
    $description = "Something to Read";
    $the_image_itself = "%".$the_image_itself;

    $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE nky_posts SET `post_title`=:title, `post_content`=:description WHERE `guid` LIKE :the_image_itself");

    $stmt->bindParam(':title', $title);
    $stmt->bindParam(':description', $description);
    $stmt->bindValue(':the_image_itself', $the_image_itself, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->debugDumpParams();
    echo "<hr/>";
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount();
```

The result looks like:

```
 start SQL: [105] UPDATE nky_posts SET `post_title`=:title,
     `post_content`=:description     
     WHERE `guid` LIKE :the_image_itself 
     Params: 3 Key: 
     Name:     [6] 
     :title paramno=-1 
     name=[6] ":title" 
     is_param=1 param_type=2 
     Key: Name: [12] :description 
     paramno=-1 name=[12] ":description" 
     is_param=1 param_type=2 
     Key: Name: [17] :the_image_itself paramno=-1 
     name=[17] ":the_image_itself" 
     is_param=1 param_type=2
```

This is the object call:

```
try{
$db=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=viewingr_ssdevwp;   charset=utf8',$db_username,$db_password);
} 
catch(PDOException $e){
echo 'Error connecting to MySQL!: '.$e->getMessage();
exit();
}
```

Comment: What am I looking for? And why aren't you using `PDO::PARAM_STR` for the other two?

Comment: Are you getting an error?  Sounds like you are dumping the statement and seeing your param placeholders and assuming that is the issue.  Might want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786322/in-php-with-pdo-how-to-check-the-final-sql-parametrized-query

Comment: thanks, @Fred -ii- . I'm not sure WHY MySQL is interpreting the placeholders by their names as opposed to their values. i'll try adding PDO::PARAM_STR to the first two.

Comment: You're welcome. Now, I also don't think you should be using `LIKE :the_image_itself` where it should probably read as `WHERE guid=:the_image_itself` (or something like that) and adding the backticks around `guid` (maybe there's something about PDO I don't know about, yet). I have a hard time showing those in comments. Then again, I might be wrong. Having a hard time wrapping my head around it right now.

Comment: I might be partially wrong AND partially right about my above comment. I think it's your `WHERE` clause that seems incomplete. @MikeiLL Something to the effect of `WHERE guid='$something'...`

Comment: I think it needs to be LIKE because I'm matching image-file-name within a string that contains a path to the image. Looking into location and access to sql logs as per @ficuscr recommendation now. on a hostmonster shared server...

Comment: Yes I agree on the `LIKE`, it's the `WHERE` that seems incomplete. @MikeiLL

Comment: '$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM nky_posts WHERE 'post_title'=:title");' doesn't even return a result set, unless i replace :title with it's value

Comment: @MikeiLL: You should use backticks (`\``) instead of single-quotes (`'`).

Comment: there seem to be some invisible characters in the result of my `basename()` call. result of var_dump looks like ` string(15) "racks.jpg
<br>
" `. Going to try adding a second ."%" to clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the "answer" is posted below, but the real answer is that I should have ceased banging my head against this problem and come back to it at a later date, which seems to be one of the most difficult things for me to do. At one point in my obsession I discovered a mysterious `<br/>` followed by some whitespaces in one of the placeholder values. I ended up doing `substr($var, 0, -6)` on the variable to remove the anomaly until noticing that I had inadvertently concatenated a `<br/>` to the end of the line that populated the variable; `.<br/>` - probably when deleting a line of output code for testing.

I was on the line with hostMonster tech support to try and get to MySQL logs because people say that that is the only place one can find out exactly WHAT MySQL is "seeing" when you use placeholders, but they don't log MySQL queries, because the file would be in the terrabytes.

At 3 or 4 am, I gave up.

Came back to it with a fresh head today and went through the following steps confirming each worked:

1. Create a *simple* SELECT statement without WHERE or placeholders:

   ```
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM nky_posts";
   ```
2. Add a WHERE clause using "=" (not LIKE) with variable being something literal I know is in the DB:

   ```
   $the_image = "image_url_from_phpMyAdmin";
   $sql = "SELECT post_title FROM nky_posts WHERE guid = $the_image";
   ```
3. Substitute the literal variable with a single placeholder holding a known value:

   ```
   $the_image = "image_url_from_phpMyAdmin";

   $stmt->bindParam(':the_image', $the_image, PDO::PARAM_STR);

   $sql = "SELECT post_title FROM nky_posts WHERE guid = :the_image";
   ```
4. Add the LIKE instead of = (remembering to concatenate placeholder variable with "%")

   ```
   $the_image = "%" . $the_image . "%";

   $stmt->bindParam(':the_image', $the_image, PDO::PARAM_STR);

   $sql = "SELECT post_title FROM nky_posts WHERE guid LIKE :the_image_itself";
   ```
5. Replace the "known" variable with dynamic variable (from XML result in this case):

   ```
   basename($oBookNode->getElementsByTagName('actual-link')->item(0)->nodeValue);
   ```

   (Using basename() function to return just the image name from URL string in wordpress database)
6. Finally replace the SELECT statement with my UPDATE statement, adding two additional placeholders to hold the variables to be inserted. Final code:

   ```
   $sql = "UPDATE nky_posts SET post_title=:title, post_content=:description WHERE guid LIKE :the_image";

   $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

   //foreach loop begins here
   foreach ($oDOM->getElementsByTagName('item') as $oBookNode)
   {

   $the_image = basename($oBookNode->getElementsByTagName('actual-link')->item(0)->nodeValue);

   $title = $oBookNode->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue;

   $description = $oBookNode->getElementsByTagName('actual-content')->item(0)->nodeValue;

   //concat % to variable for LIKE clause (probably only needed first one in this case, but...)

   $the_image = "%" . $the_image . "%";


   $stmt->bindParam(':title', $title, PDO::PARAM_STR);

   $stmt->bindParam(':description', $description, PDO::PARAM_STR);

   $stmt->bindParam(':the_image_itself', $another_image_itself, PDO::PARAM_STR);

   $stmt->execute();
   //end foreach loop
   }
   ```

   Thanks for the help, everyone.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where you got the impression that [`debugDumpParams()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.debugdumpparams.php) will display the raw SQL query -- **it will not**. When using parameterized queries, you create a prepared statement at the database, and *then* send the parameter values **alone**. They are not sent together, meaning there's no way print the raw SQL query.

`debugDumpParams()` will only display the list of parameters, their names, types etc. but *not* their values. One thing you can do, however, is to inspect your MySQL query log to see the raw SQL query that was executed.

Once you've found the logs, you can use the following command to see the recently executed queries (provided you have SSH access):

```
$ sudo tail -f /usr/local/mysql/data/yourQueryLog.log
```

The above path is just an example. The actual path might be different on your system.

Comment: +1. What you say about debugDumpParams is true. But with MySQL, I believe PDO defaults to only emulating prepared statements with MySQL. To get actual "server side" prepared statements, I think you have to explicitly set a PDO option... `setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES,false)`.

Comment: tried adding `$stmt->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES,false);`. Not even sure it's expected to work as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16264769/setting-pdoattr-emulate-prepares-to-false-not-working

Comment: Hosting tech support is telling me the .mysql_history is empty. That it possibly only logs command line queries. Seems odd. They "created a ticket".

Comment: @MikeiLL: Can you try this with `?` instead of named placeholders? That *might* work.

Comment: @Mike ILL: by default, PDO doesn's use "server side" prepared statements; I was addressing what Amal said.. using placeholders in the SQL text is not synonymous with "server side" prepared statements; not all databases and drivers support "server side" prepared statements. PDO emulates them. The code looks like it's doing prepared statements, but PDO is actually creating a SQL statement with literals and sending that to the database. To see the statements being received by the MySQL server, enable the MySQL general_log.

Comment: @spencer7593: Absolutely correct. You have to explicitly enable it using `setAttribute()`. I'm not sure if I should edit the answer to include that (feel free to edit if you want).

Comment: @MikeiLL: If you're using phpMyAdmin, take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14404000/1438393) to see how to enable query log.

Answer (score 0):

The output from the `debugDumpParams` function call looks right.

That `debugDumpParams` function doesn't display the values of the bind parameters; it only shows the SQL text along with the placeholder names/positions, and their respective datatypes.

I'm not sure I understood the question you asked.

---

There's no need to invoke the `fetchAll` method on stmt, since it is an `UPDATE` statement.

Note that for `rowCount`, MySQL returns the number of rows that were actually changed by the statement, not the number of rows matched. That is, if the values in the columns being set were already set to the specified value, then MySQL doesn't "count" that row as being affected.

Comment: Question is why doesn't the placeholder seem to be passing the value to mysql. Even sending a simple SELECT `$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM nky_posts WHERE 'post_title'=:title")` returns null. Returns correctly with Actual Data in where clause.